# Why does Swift closure syntax not accept the use of return when the parameter is implicit?

Tags: swift

What is the reasoning behind the language design of Swift to make the following acceptable

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].map({ (number:Int)->Int in return number * 3 })  // ok
```

or

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].map({ number in number * 3 })  // ok
```

or

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].map({ 3 * $0 })  // ok
```

while making this not acceptable?

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].map({ return 3 * $0 })  // not ok
```

Comment: I'm leaning towards compiler bug.

Answer (score 3):

It's clearly a compiler bug, because moving the closure to a separate variable it works:

```
let closure1: (Int) -> (Int) = { return 3 * $0 }
var closure2: (Int) -> (Int) = { return 3 * $0 }
[1, 2, 3, 4].map( closure1 ) // Works
[1, 2, 3, 4].map( closure2 ) // Works
[1, 2, 3, 4].map( { return 3 * $0 } ) // Fails
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug in the type inference engine. For example:

```
[1, 2, 3].map({ return 3 * $0 } as Int -> Int)
```

is fine.

Edit: Removed some nonsense thanks to @Antonio's comment.

Comment: Note that `var i = { return 3 * $0 }` fails because type inference cannot figure out what $0 is - so a compilation error is the expected behavior

Comment: You mean the type inference cannot figure out what $0 is... due to a compiler bug. There's nothing should be reasonably preventing it (especially since it can figure it out if you remove the "return" keyword)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is a beta6 compiler bug. Note that the following does work (adding an explicit type):

```
let z:[Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4].map({ return 3 * $0 })
```

I would check this again in the next beta.